# ActiveMQ 5.15.4 STOMP 1.2 behavior unexpected

Tags: c, activemq-classic, stomp

Below I am trying to execute the STOMP commands via netcat and when I try to get a receipt for the first message I receive the 2nd message unexpectedly (a RECEIPT and MESSAGE) when I only expected a RECEIPT to come back from the server. The below commands are executed with 4 messages on the queue. Please advise.

Sent to server

```
CONNECT
login: sender_receiver
passcode:sender_receiver
accept-version:1.2

^@
```

From the server

```
CONNECTED
server:ActiveMQ/5.15.4
heart-beat:0,0
session:ID:centos7-42009-1529845487133-3:5
version:1.2
```

Sent to the server

```
SUBSCIBE
destination:/queue/queueName
activemq.prefetchSize:1
ack:client
id:12345

^@
```

Received from server

```
MESSAGE
content-length:9
expires:0
destination:/queue/queueName
ack:ID\ccentos7-42009-1529845487133-14\c1
subscription:12345
priority:4
redelivered:true
message-id:ID\ccentos7-42009-1529845487133-3\c4\c-1\c1\c1
persistent:true
timestamp:1529845914578

message 0
```

Sent to server

```
ACK
receipt:ack_id_receipt
id:ID\ccentos7-42009-1529845487133-14\c1

^@
```

Received from server

```
RECEIPT
receipt-id:ack_id_receipt

MESSAGE
content-length:9
expires:0
destination:/queue/queueName
ack:ID\ccentos7-42009-1529845487133-16\c2
subscription:12345
priority:4
message-id:ID\ccentos7-42009-1529845487133-3\c10\c-1\c1\c2
persistent:true
timestamp:1529863616319

message 1
```

Comment: Can you include the corresponding netcat commands at each step?

Comment: I used 1 netcat command to call all of the commands. > nc 127.0.0.1 61613

Comment: Can you describe in any more detail how you do that?

Comment: 1) create an activemq instance 2) insert 4 messages on a queue named 'queueName' 3) started nc localhost 61613 (single netcat session) on the same server as ActiveMQ  4) Typed all the "sent to server" commands above into the netcat session and received the responses from the server listed above labeled "received from server". Please let me know if you need further details. thanks.